# Control multiple addressable RGB LED Strips (ws2812) with Raspberry PI

Tags: led, pwm

I'm building a project where I would like to control multiple addressable RGB LED strips with Raspberry Pi Zero.

Initially I've done everything using PWM0 (pins 12, 18) and PWM1 (13, 19), however now I would like to add audio output for this project.

Apparently audio uses PWM pins 12 and 13, so of course switching modes using `dtoverlay=audremap,pins_12_13` breaks interaction with LEDs.

I mistakenly bought PCA9685 thinking that it will help me to control multiple strips through I2C however it seems that I was wrong, and I couldn't make it work.

So do you have any recommendations what I can explore in this case?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD1**

Sorry if I wasn't clear before, I currently use led strips like this:

```py
import board
import neopixel


led_strip_1_size = 15
led_strip_1 = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, led_strip_1_size, brightness=0.5, auto_write=False)

led_strip_2_size = 10
led_strip_2 = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D21, led_strip_2_size, auto_write=False)



def fill_pixels(pixels, n, color):
    pixels.fill(color)
    pixels.show()


def clear_pixels(pixels, n):
    fill_pixels(pixels, n, (0, 0, 0))


fill_pixels(led_strip_1, led_strip_1_size, (255, 0, 0))
fill_pixels(led_strip_2, led_strip_2_size, (0, 255, 0))
```

When I connect Audio to pin 12,13 and enable `dtoverlay=audremap,pins_12_13` LEDs stop working.

Audio start working with `aplay`

I would like to have multiple parallel LEDs working with Pi and Audio.

Comment: What about hdmi audio or usb audio?

Comment: If you want any help you need to explain (in your Question) WHAT YOU DID.

Comment: Why are you using PWM pins (and a PWM device) for WS2812 strips in the first place?

Comment: @Milliways what exactly am I missing?

Comment: @JaromandaX what other I can use?

Comment: @CoderMike I think that's an option, I'm just trying to explore using PWM before I buy usb audio card.

Comment: Incidentally analog audio uses PWM but DOES NOT use GPIO12,13

Comment: I may not understand how you're using PWM for your WS2812 strips

Comment: @Milliways thanks, tried to add more context

Comment: @Jaromanda X explained it in the post, using NeoPixel library for that